# compare two vectors in r, while and if structure

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, while-loop, compare

I have been trying to code this exemple with while loops and if structure but I did not manage to do it. There is always a problem with my synthax.

if x1 >= x2 result = 1
else result = -1

```
x1 x2 result
 5  7   -1
 3  4   -1
 7  2    1
```

If anyone manage to get the correct synthax I would be really thankful

Comment: You essentially have a TRUE/FALSE binary split here. `ifelse(x1 >= x2, 1, -1)` I think. Or just `x1 >= x2` if you can work with a `TRUE/FALSE` output.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It sounds like you specifically want `while()` and `if()` to show up in your solution, but those are not needed to get your result column (as @thelatemail just showed). If you really want to use `while()`, then please provide an example of the non-working syntax.

Comment: Could you specify how your is data encoded? Are they two separate vectors or do you already have them in a data frame and just wish to add a new 'result' column?

Answer (score 0):

I like using `dplyr` for these kinds of problems. We can tackle this problem in more efficient ways than using loops

```
# make up some data
library(dplyr)
mydat <- data.frame(x = seq(1:10), y = rev(seq(10:1)))


#calculate result

new_data <- mutate(mydat, result = ifelse(x >= y, "1", "-1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get your answers and none of them needs a  **while loop**  as  **vectorized solutions**  must allways be of intrest. My prefered one would be :

```
result = (x1>=X2) -(x1<X2)
```

But this method does the comparison twice and so, is not efficient. You can use its mathematical equivalent one, which is :

```
result = 2*(x1>=X2) - 1
```

But if you prefer not to use maths, another pure R way of doing it would be:

```
result = rep(1,length(x1))
result[x1<X2] = -1
```